# Missing elements in Product-list.tpl when use BlockLayered module (AJAX refresh)

Tags: ajax, prestashop

Im facing a problem with BlockLayered module. Product-list.tpl loses their elements (table with data obtained from array) when AJAX call (BlockLayered filter) refresh the page...

[image]

Im not sure where to find solution. There also missing **Dodaj do schowka** button (favoriteproducts module)

Answer (score 1):

Module *blocklayered* in `ajaxCall()` method uses its own data to pass into *product-list.tpl* template, so if you e.g. overrided some core methods to pass additional data in template (as I see you did), *blocklayered* know nothing about it and will ignore it during ajax page updates.

To fix it put you changes in `ajaxCall()` method too. Do not forget, from version 1.6.1.1 Prestashop allow use modules override, so you can leave original *blocklayered.php* unchanged, for further updates.

**upd** explanations with code:

- in `ajaxCall` method you need to have something like

  `$smarty->assign(
              array(
                  'myQuantity' => 10,
                  'homeSize' => ...,
                  'nb_products' => $nb_products,
  ...
  ));`
- then in *product-list.tpl*

  `{if isset($myQantity)} 
      {$myQantity} 
  {/if}`

it works.

Comment: Thanks for this good hint. It looks like ajaxCall need to be extended for some lines. I was trying to extend it via add ' 'quantityDiscount' => utf8_encode($quantity_discount), ' but without any success

Comment: Smarty cache disabled? try to put in template file `{debug}` do you see your `quantityDiscount` there? also i guess $quantity_discount is an integer and not need to encode it in utf8

Comment: No success. Debug not show any quantityDiscount variable at all.

Comment: I updated my answer, it works as described P.S. {debug} will not works you can delete it

Comment: it was so easy. Good hint. I have use something like {if isset($myQuantity)}Test text{/if} and this text show up after use ot the blocklayered but is not present before use. I will try to make it work but im not programmer at all...

Comment: Still cant figure this out how to show my content instead of "10" value of "myQuantity" variable... @Sergii P help pls

Comment: Hey @PipBoy2000 I answered in your second question, hope it will help!